# how to open a popup (popup.html) whenever we click on browser's button(browserAction) using crossrider

Tags: google-chrome-extension, crossrider

I am working on to develop extensions using crossrider . I have added popup.html file to resources of my extension , but how to link it to onclick event of a browser button .I have been trying with appAPI.tabs.create('popup.html') to atleast open the popup file in a new tab but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for explicit linking of popup.html to onclick event of browser button if you have registered [manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#manifest) as below.

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Google Mail",      // optional; shown in tooltip
    "default_popup": "popup.html"        // This registers to onclick event of browser icon
  },
  ...
}
```

### References:

[Browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html)

Let me know if you need more information.